# Can you connect to Dynamics GP from an Azure worker role?

Tags: azure, dynamics-gp

I'm looking into the possibility of integrating an Azure hosted .NET solution with Dynamics GP and I'm new to Dynamics.  In general it seems like there are two approaches to connecting to GP: 1) web services and 2) eConnect.  [This article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/developingfordynamicsgp/archive/2012/04/27/choosing-between-econnect-for-microsoft-dynamics-gp-and-web-services-for-microsoft-dynamics-gp.aspx) has some good background.

I would think as long as the web services are accessible, that option would work.  I see that there are MSMQ and other requirements for eConnect which makes me think that would be a headache if it is even possible without something like Azure Connect.  Has anyone has done this one way or the other?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can connect to your Dynamics GP from a Windows Azure Worker role (why Worker, why not web role?) and it's all depend which route your would want to take.

Web Services method is comparatively neat & easier to access your Secure Web Services configured Dynamics GP.

On the other hand, eConnect Integration requires several other configurations so If you decided to use eConnect, I think you are better of using eConnect along with BizTalk Server/Adapter combination set into Service Bus (which is talking directly to eConnect) and your Azure application is talking to BizTalk services directly. This could be much easier to implement but you can not beat web services.

Comment: Thanks.  In response to your question, tne scenario I had in mind was Worker Role specific, but I think on the whole I was thinking of the web/worker scenarios as opposed to requiring a VM Role to make lots of required configurations.  If you can provide any links on the BizTalk - Service Bus architecture mentioned it would be appreciated, too. Thanks

Comment: I would suggest to avoid VM Role because it is still in Beta and not much improvements are added to it. Depend on how do you want to use BizTalk with SB there are couple of ways i.e. EAI/EDI http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh689760.aspx and a direct approach as http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh542796.aspx

Comment: Sorry, I meant Virtual Machine instead of VM Role.

Comment: Windows Azure Virtual Machines are fine.